# Can I pass a function as a class attribute and call it?

Tags: python, class, oop

Can I actually use functions of another class as a parameter and attribute for a class instance/object?

I noticed if I do something like this there are lots of oddities (Note that I use Jupyter lab):

```
class ObjectClass:
    #A class; I will insert a function into generalMethod
    def __init__(self, generalMethod):
        self.generalMethod = generalMethod

class GeneralMethods():    
    #Two different methods that I want to call
    def method1(self):
        add(2)
    def method2(self):
        print("Hey now, you're an all-star, get your game on, go play" )
        return "Hey, I can return stuff, at least!",2

def add(input):
    #A simple function that adds 1 to input
    print(1 + input)

#Creating two objects with different methods as inputs from GeneralMethods
gm = GeneralMethods()
object1 = ObjectClass(gm.method1())
object2 = ObjectClass(gm.method2())

#Attempting to call anything from generalMethod; a getter method does the same
object1.generalMethod
object2.generalMethod
```

`gm.method1()` and `gm.method2()` does everything inside it, *even* when I simply declare it as a parameter of the object/instance!

But `anyObject.generalMethod` doesn't do anything *besides* return whatever is in the return when I call it, and if a function is in there, it will return `None`.

So can I actually call a function from the attribute and it perform like gm.method1() does when calling it from the attribute (`anyObjectIChoose.generalMethod`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function as parameter:

```
def foo():
    print('hello')

def bar(_f):
    _f()

bar(_f=foo)
'hello'
```

Note that when you add `()` to function's name, you invoke it. To pass as param you need just the name, not invoke it.